# Plot in R, without displaying zero values but keeping the same indexing

Tags: r

I have the following vector `x` with each corresponding index vector.

```
x = c(0,-50,-65,0,0,-58,0)
index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

and when I plot them (index,x) I take the following

```
plot(index,x)
```

However, is there a way to display a plot that has the same indexing i.e. the same (index,x) order, but doesn't display the points with `x=0`.

I don't want to plot these points in order for my plot to "focus-zoom" on the negative values.

Is there a way to that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
We could assign `NA` to `0`:

```
is.na(x) <- x== 0
x
plot(index,x)
```

[image]

First answer:
Are you looking for such a solution?

```
plot(index,x, ylim=c(min(x), -10))
```

[image]

Comment: I feel stupid :/ it was so simple

Comment: That is a way to solve that, but I'm also wondering if there is a more directed to that problem solution

Comment: @Jonathan1234 Never mind. Just ask to feel better. There is no stupid question!

Comment: Please see my update. Just assign NA to 0.